# Prove that there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A \subseteq \overline{B(x,\text{diam}(A))}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, metric-spaces, solution-verification

The problem is

> Show that if $0 < \text{diam}(A) < \infty$ , then
> there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A \subseteq \overline{B(x,\text{diam}(A))}$

My proof:

Since the definition of diameter ensures that $A$ is nonempty, there exists an $x \in A.$ Now, let $a \in A$ be arbitrarily chosen, then

$$ d(a,x) \leq \text{diam}(A) \implies a\in \overline{B(x,\text{diam}(A))}.$$ We conclude that $A \subseteq \overline{B(x,\text{diam}(A))}$.

It seems too short as a problem, and I suspect that I was making some wrong argument. Could anyone help me check my solution? Thanks.

Comment: @angryavian The texts says the best result is provided by Jung's Theorem, which states that the bound is $\sqrt{ \frac{n}{2(n+1)} }diam(A)$

Comment: @angryavian half the diameter won't work with a triangle in the plane

Comment: In  a general metric space the closed ball of radius $r$ around a point is different from the closure of the open ball of radius $r$ around that point. So your proof is not complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: Your solution is correct.

---

You also already know that the optimal radius is less than that and we can go on step in that direction:
Let $D=\operatorname{diam}(A)$. As also $\operatorname{diam}(\overline A)=D$, we may assume wlog that $A$ is compact, so there are points $a,b\in A$ with $d(a,b)=D$. Then
$$A\subseteq\overline{B(a,D)}\cap \overline{B(b,D)}  $$
The lens shape on the right can be covered from its center $c=\frac{a+b}2$ with radius $r$ given by Pythagoras, i.e., $(D/2)^2+r^2=D^2$.$^1$ In other words, this already improves our result to
$$ A\subset \overline{B\bigl(\tfrac{a+b}2,\tfrac{\sqrt3}2D\bigr)}$$

---

$^1$ That is: A quick computation shows that $(x-a)^2\le D^2 \land (x-b)^2\le D^2$ implies $(x-c)^2\le \frac34 D^2$